# Is there anything like MessageBox/SQL binds for normal strings?

Tags: peoplesoft

#### Context

In PeopleCode, the following declaration with `MessageBox` is valid:

```
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "Something = %1, Something else = %2.", &something, &somethingElse);
```

This allows me to use bind variables for the `MessageBox`. The same is also true with SQL:

```
SQLExec("SELECT * FROM %Table(:1) WHERE VALUE = :2", Record.Y_SOMETHING, &value);
```

#### Question

Is there a way to do that with normal strings? I've never liked having to "pipe" strings together like this `&string = Something = " | &something | ", Something else = " | &somethingElse | "."`.

Is there a way to use this format for regular strings? I've looked through various of Oracle's PeopleBooks, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
Local number &message_set, &message_num;
Local string &default_msg_txt = "%1 %2 %3";
Local string &l_result= MsgGetText(&message_set, &message_num, &default_msg_txt, "hallo", "Frank", "!");
```

result:

```
"hallo Frank !"
```

You can use `MsgGetText` function to determine a message by message catalogue. In case the message is not found, the default text is used.

Comment: Interesting "hack". Anyways, that answers my question.